# NPE on AttributeDescriptorModel.getLocalized()

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, commerce, smartedit

While adding smartEdit components I am getting null pointer for 'AttributeDescriptorModel.getLocalized()'. I did try searching any of such model with below groovy but it is not giving me any result. Since this is on environment so I cannot debug it. Below is groovy and logs

```
def SCRIPT_QUERY = "select {pk} from {attributeDescriptor}"
def attributeDescriptors = flexibleSearchService.search(SCRIPT_QUERY).getResult()
println ("groovy start-----------")
for (attributeDescriptor in attributeDescriptors) {
if(attributeDescriptor.getLocalized()==null)
{println(attributeDescriptor.getName())}}
println ("groovy end-----------")
```

Below is logs

> loggerName":"de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.resolver.AbstractRestHandlerExceptionResolver","message":"java.lang.NullPointerException: 
> Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" because the return value of "de.hybris.platform.core.model.type.AttributeDescriptorModel.getLocalized()" is null 
> \n\tat de.hybris.platform.cms2.common.predicates.IsCollectionAttributePredicate.test(IsCollectionAttributePredicate.java:21) 
> \n\tat de.hybris.platform.cms2.common.predicates.IsCollectionAttributePredicate.test(IsCollectionAttributePredicate.java:17) 
> n\tat de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.types.populator.DropdownComponentTypeAttributePopulator.populate(DropdownComponentTypeAttributePopulator.java:38) 
> \n\tat de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.types.populator.DropdownComponentTypeAttributePopulator.populate(DropdownComponentTypeAttributePopulator.java:25) 
> \n\tat de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.types.converter.ComponentTypeStructureConverter.lambda$convertAttribute$5(ComponentTypeStructureConverter.java:183) 
> \n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)\n\tat de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.types.converter.ComponentTypeStructureConverter.convertAttribute(ComponentTypeStructureConverter.java:183)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Login to HAC and try to update all extensions:

HAC > Platform > Update > Choose all options: Update running system, Create essential data, Localize types and toggle all > click on "update"

[image]